# How do I update my routing table to accommodate VPN without using remote gateway?

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, routing

Windows 7 x64

I have a VPN connection to my work network.  It works fine if I have the "Use default gateway on remote network" is checked, but I don't want that.  I know I need to update my routing table so that traffic intended for the work network is directed to that network, before all remaining traffic is routed through the local gateway.

I am having trouble figuring out how to identify the correct settings for the routing table.  I know that I will have a defualt traffic entry for "0.0.0.0", which will need to have a higher metric than traffic specifically routed to the work network, but how can I determine the correct gateway and interface for the work/VPN network?  When I do ipconfig /all, it just shows the gateway as "On-link", and the IP address assigned by the remote network changes between connections (DHCP).

Any help in this matter is appreciated.

Edit:
It appears that if I add a specific route e.g.:

`route -p -4 ADD 192.168.30.55 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.50.1`

it works, but if I add a range e.g.:

`route -p -4 ADD 192.168.30.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.50.1`

it doesn't.  Any ideas why the second one doesn't work?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have the wrong subnet mask. 255.255.255.0 is a very uncommon subnet mask for VPNs.

Connect using your VPN and post your ipconfig & routing tables. Or if you know what VPN software you use, we can just look at the config files.